# How to solve $\int_{1}^{e^{37}}\frac{\pi sin\left(\pi \ln(x)\right)}{x}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

**Question** How to solve $\int_{1}^{e^{37}}\frac{\pi sin\left(\pi \ln(x)\right)}{x}\, dx$

**My Approach** I don't have any idea about it .Please give me some
hints.

**Edit** I made this post just for a hint to approach.I successfully got it,now i can solve it .Thanks for posting comments and answer

Comment: @Cornman Thanks for edit

Comment: Let $\pi\ln x=u$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Make $\log(x)=t\implies x=e^t\implies dx=e^t\,dt$ and see what happens for the antiderivative.

Comment: Indeed it was very easy.it is only the outfit that made it to look difficult.